# Delete first non-nil sub-array element from a Ruby 2D Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given one has an array where each item is an array, but can be empty, such as:

```
a = [ [], [8, 6], [7, 5, 3, 0], [], [9] ]
```

One can delete the first non-nil sub-array element by:

```
a[a.index { |item| item != [] }].shift
```

Leaving `a` in this state:

```
[ [], [6], [7, 5, 3, 0], [], [9] ]
```

Is there a more concise way of expressing this in Ruby, with or without passing `a.index { |item| item != [] }` as the index of the subarray to delete from?

Comment: Could you show what you want `a` to be when you're done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable#find`:

```
a.find { |e| !e.empty? }.shift
=> 8
a
=> [[], [6], [7, 5, 3, 0], [], [9]]
```

Comment: Ah, of course! "Find the first thing that isn't empty and shift it."

Comment: You could avoid the negative with `e.any?` and could use [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) if you want the expression to return the modified array: `a.tap { |b| b.find { |e| e.any? }.shift } #=> [[], [6], [7, 5, 3, 0], [], [9]]`(and `a` is now the same).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the sub-arrays with empty arrays. This works for the exact stated problem, but may not extrapolate into what you're looking for.

```
a.map{[]}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've clarified my question and made the code more specific regarding the question.